# Rails trying to create nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Ok i'm shooting to have a url like this `/applications/:application_id/jobseekers/new`. I know if i generate 2 scaffolds (applications and jobseekers) i could make the routes work by doing this:

```
resources :applications do
  resources :jobseekers
end
```

but i don't need a full scaffold for jobseekers. I only need a new and create method.

How can i write my routes so that the jobseekers#new and jobseekers#create methods work?

I tried

```
resources :applications do 
    get '/applications/:application_id/jobseekers/new', :to => 'jobseekers#new', :as => :new_application_jobseeker
    post '/applications/:application_id/jobseekers', :to => 'jobseekers#create'
  end
```

but it gives me this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/applications/3/jobseekers/new"
```

when hitting this url:

```
localhost:3000/applications/3/jobseekers/new
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the actions you want as follows:

```
resources :applications do
  resources :jobseekers, :only=> [:new, :create]
end
```

Comment: Ahh nice solution. Was not aware of this.

Comment: Seems I was too late! Hope my answer was useful anyway.

Comment: @shioyama, you took the time to explain what Catfish was already doing wrong, nice answer. :)

Comment: @Catfish, `only` also has a counterpart - `except` which you can use if you just want to exclude a couple of actions.

Comment: Good to know. IMHO, routing in rails seems like it's much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your routes is that your are including the full path (`'/applications/:application_id/jobseekers/new'`) *inside* a nested route. Instead, you need to put your `get` and `post` calls into a member block:

```
resources :applications do
  member do
    get "jobseekers/new", :to => 'jobseekers#new'
    post "jobseekers", :to => 'jobseekers#create'
  end
end
```

By doing this, Rails will match `/applications/:id/` part will be prepended to `"jobseekers/new"` to get the full route, which you can see if you call `rake routes`:

```
new_application_jobseeker_application GET    /applications/:id/jobseekers/new(.:format) jobseekers#new
               jobseekers_application POST   /applications/:id/jobseekers(.:format)     jobseekers#create
```

Alternatively, you can define a nested resource and include only the `new` and `create` actions with the `only` option:

```
resources :applications do
  resources :jobseekers, :only=> [:new, :create]
end
```

Note that the path helpers will be slightly different in this case, and will use `application_id` rather than `id` for the id of the application:

```
   application_jobseekers POST   /applications/:application_id/jobseekers(.:format)     jobseekers#create
new_application_jobseeker GET    /applications/:application_id/jobseekers/new(.:format) jobseekers#new
```

Comment: Good information. Thanks for this. What does the "member" do?

Comment: `member do` says that you want whatever you do in the block to apply to the route for a member of the resource collection, i.e. a single application, expressed in your route as `application/:id`. If you instead use `collection do` then it will apply to the whole collection (of applications), with a path `application/`. In your case, if you used `collection do` you would get routes `'/applications/jobseekers/new'` and `''/applications/jobseekers/create'`. But you need the id of the application in there, so you should use a member route.

Comment: The Rails guide on routing has detailed explanations of each: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks for the info. It's very helpful.

Comment: I've skimmed through that routing guide so many times, but i never seem to find what i'm looking for in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the table with a migration, and a model and a controller manually, then add only the methods you want.

```
rails g model jobseekers
```

etc.

Comment: I don't actually want a model for jobseekers as i'm just using this controller to modify another model. I need 2 separate controllers.

Comment: Your answer also doesn't not explain why my route does not work.